# Is there a tool that can export or import an object from the database

Tags: mysql, database, database-relations

The object I am referring to is about a entity in the data model.

For example, these are the tables in my database:

```
-- ----------------------------
-- student
-- ----------------------------
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `student`;
CREATE TABLE `student` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `student_no` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `name` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  `gender` tinyint(1) NOT NULL,
  `age` tinyint(3) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

INSERT INTO `student` VALUES ('1', '19001', 'John', '1', '13');
INSERT INTO `student` VALUES ('2', '19002', 'Mary', '2', '12');
INSERT INTO `student` VALUES ('3', '19003', 'Tom', '1', '13');

-- ----------------------------
-- course
-- ----------------------------
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `course`;
CREATE TABLE `course` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `name` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

INSERT INTO `course` VALUES ('1', 'C1');
INSERT INTO `course` VALUES ('2', 'C2');
INSERT INTO `course` VALUES ('3', 'C3');

-- ----------------------------
-- score
-- ----------------------------
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `score`;
CREATE TABLE `score` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `course_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `student_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `score` int(11) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

INSERT INTO `score` VALUES ('1', '1', '1', '100');
INSERT INTO `score` VALUES ('2', '1', '2', '96');
INSERT INTO `score` VALUES ('3', '2', '1', '77');
```

Student entity includes all data associated with it.

I want to export a student entity named Mary, including all of its associated data (courses, scores)

Through the tool, I want to get the output like the following:

#### 1. json like formats:

```
{
    "id": 2,
    "student_no": 19002,
    "name": "Mary",
    "gender": 2,
    "age": 12,
    "score": [
        {
            "id": 2,
            "course_id": 1,
            "student_id": 2,
            "score": 96
        }
    ]
}
```

#### 2. INSERT statments

```
INSERT INTO `student` (`id`, `student_no`, `name`, `gender`, `age`) VALUES ('2', '19002', 'Mary', '2', '12');

INSERT INTO `score` (`id`, `course_id`, `student_id`, `score`) VALUES ('2', '1', '2', '96');
```

Any of the above two formats can help achieve my goal.

#### purpose

The data associated with Mary is the student record and her course score records, so I hope that this tool can help me transfer data from one database to another, or easily delete any associated records about Mary in a database instead of write the SQL statement myself.

Is there such a tool? The tool should be configurable without writing code, to define the tables involved in the entity and the associated fields between them.

Thank you!

Comment: Which RDBMS? ("Newer" SQL Server it's pretty easy for example while I don't know a way of doing it in MySQL without writing code)

Comment: Sorry for that, I'm using mysql...